# Getting compilation error: "identifier 'objUser' is undefined" in my main() function

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors

I'm trying to call the functions from my clsFamily class within the main, however, when I pass down the (&objUser) I get a message stating:

> identifier 'objUser' is undefined

Edit: Sorry forgot to mention but I want a dynamic vector array that is manipulated based on the users choice.

Any help at all will be kindly appreciated as it is for an assignment that is due next Thursday xD

```
int UserChoice();

int UserChoice()
{
 int iChoice = 0;
 int iAdults = 0;
 int iChildren = 0;

 cout << "How many family members do you have? \n";
 cin >> iChoice;

 cout << "How many of these are adults? \n";
 cin >> iAdults;

 cout << "How many of these are children? \n";
 cin >> iChildren;

 return iChoice;
 return iAdults;
 return iChildren;
}

class clsUser
 {
  private:
    string m_sName;
    int m_iAge;
  public:
    void SetName(string);
    string GetName();
    void SetAge(int);
    int GetAge();
    clsUser();
    ~clsUser();
    clsUser(string, int);
  };

//This is to group the singular users into a group using a vector
class clsFamily
{
 private:
  vector <clsUser> objUser;
  public:
  void InputFamilyDetails(vector <clsUser> *objUser);
  void OutputFamilyDetails(vector <clsUser> *objUser);
};

void clsFamily::InputFamilyDetails(vector <clsUser>* objUser)
{
 string sName = "";
 int iAge = 0;

 for (int iCount = 0; iCount < objUser->size(); iCount++)
 {
     cout << "Please enter the name of family member " << iCount + 1 << "\n";
     cin >> sName;

     cout << "Please enter the age of family member " << iCount + 1 << "\n";
     cin >> iAge;

     objUser->at(iCount).SetName(sName);
     objUser->at(iCount).SetAge(iAge);
 }
}
//This is to allow the user to input the the details of the users from the vector

void clsFamily::OutputFamilyDetails(vector <clsUser>* objUser)
{
 for (int iCount = 0; iCount < objUser->size(); iCount++)
 {
     cout << "The name of family member " << iCount + 1 << " is " << objUser->at(iCount).GetName() << " \n";
     cout << "The age of family member " << iCount + 1 << " is " << objUser->at(iCount).GetAge()<< " \n";
 }
}

int main()
{
 clsFamily objFamily;
 *//This is the area where the problem is occuring*
 objFamily.InputFamilyDetails(&objUser);
 objFamily.OutputFamilyDetails(&objUser);
}
```

Comment: please use a title that describes your problem

Comment: `std::vector <clsUser> objUse(42);` seems missing from `main`.

Comment: (Aside: with a bit of editing, this doesn't look like a bad question. If you can post in the future minus the chat and pleading, you may even get some upvotes! Good luck with your problem).

Answer (score 2):

`clsFamily` already has an `objUser` member. You shouldn't use it and not expect a parameter in `InputFamiliyDetails` and `OutputFamilyDetails`:

```cpp
class clsFamily
{
 private:
  vector <clsUser> objUser; // Needs to be initialized with some size, though
  public:
  void InputFamilyDetails();
  void OutputFamilyDetails();
};

void clsFamily::InputFamilyDetails()
{
 string sName = "";
 int iAge = 0;

 for (int iCount = 0; iCount < objUser.size(); iCount++)
 {
     cout << "Please enter the name of family member " << iCount + 1 << "\n";
     cin >> sName;

     cout << "Please enter the age of family member " << iCount + 1 << "\n";
     cin >> iAge;

     objUser.at(iCount).SetName(sName);
     objUser.at(iCount).SetAge(iAge);
 }
}

void clsFamily::OutputFamilyDetails()
{
 for (int iCount = 0; iCount < objUser.size(); iCount++)
 {
     cout << "The name of family member " << iCount + 1 << " is " << objUser.at(iCount).GetName() << " \n";
     cout << "The age of family member " << iCount + 1 << " is " << objUser.at(iCount).GetAge()<< " \n";
 }
}

int main()
{
 clsFamily objFamily;
 objFamily.InputFamilyDetails();
 objFamily.OutputFamilyDetails();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help mate. However would this still work if I was to create a dynamic vector array based upon the user's input? For example user inputs 5 family members, 5 memory blocks are allocated to the vector?